# Excel: #NA error while using index and match

Tags: excel

[image]

I'm working with excel 2016. I am trying to use INDEX and MATCH to insert numbers into the ALT COST/ACRE. the screenshot is the first table.

I'm trying to insert ZIP AVG PRICE/ACRE from table 2, which looks like:

[image: v]

into ALT COST/ACRE

my attempt , as you can see in the first screenshot is :

```
=INDEX(Table2[[zip avg price/acre]:[ZIP2]],MATCH([@ZIP],Table2[[#Headers],[ZIP2]],0),1)
```

However this results in a

```
#NA
```

error. How can I fix this?

Comment: may be instead of using named range, try substituting those with Cell address, .....   also if you were to do it manually, what would be your sample answer ,,,, that will also help to understand what you want to get done !!!

Comment: `Table2[[#Headers],[ZIP2]]` => `Table2[ZIP2]`?

Comment: @GSerg, that worked, do you want to enter it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table2[[#Headers],[ZIP2]]` [represents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e#__examples_of_using) the single header cell that contains the column name, `ZIP2`.
As you want to search for `[@ZIP]` in the entire column `ZIP2` rather than in its header cell, you should replace it with `Table2[ZIP2]` which is the data portion of the ZIP2 column:

```
=INDEX(Table2[[zip avg price/acre]:[ZIP2]], MATCH([@ZIP],Table2[ZIP2],0), 1)
```

Then you could note that the `INDEX` is not using the second column out of the `Table2[[zip avg price/acre]:[ZIP2]]`, at which point it would become:

```
=INDEX(Table2[zip avg price/acre], MATCH([@ZIP],Table2[ZIP2],0), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you .just for my understanding what is the difference between [@ZIP] and [ZIP] ?

Comment: @user1592380 `[@ZIP]` is the intersection of the column `ZIP` and the current row. `[ZIP]` is the entire column `ZIP`.